# My laptop can not access internet after setup bridge with wired NIC and wireless NIC

Tags: wireless, networking, network-bridge, wireless-access-point, hostapd

I setup a bridge using wired NIC and wireless NIC in order to make wireless NIC as a Wi-Fi AP to share wired internet access, after setup successfully, the Wi-Fi AP works as my expectation, but my laptop can not access internet, please give me a hand. Thanks.

My hostapd.conf

```
$ cat hostapd.conf 
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
ssid=myAP
hw_mode=g
channel=11
dtim_period=1
rts_threshold=2347
fragm_threshold=2346
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=3
ieee80211n=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=PassWord
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Setup steps:

```
$ sudo killall hostapd
hostapd: no process found
$ sudo hostapd -B hostapd.conf
Configuration file: hostapd.conf
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr 00:26:5e:e8:4f:8e and ssid 'myAP'
$ sudo brctl addbr br0
device br0 already exists; can't create bridge with the same name
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 up
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 0.0.0.0 up
$ sudo brctl addif br0 eth0
$ sudo brctl addif br0 wlan0
device wlan0 is already a member of a bridge; can't enslave it to bridge br0.
$ sudo ifconfig br0 192.168.1.110 netmask 255.255.255.0
$ sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```

The chrome prompts:

```
The server at stackoverflow.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.



$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.





^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
64 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 63456ms


$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.00265ee84f8e   no      eth0
                            wlan0


$ ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:5e:e8:4f:8e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.115  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::226:5eff:fee8:4f8e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4038 (4.0 KB)  TX bytes:8111 (8.1 KB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:d6:5e:f8:6a:22  
          inet6 addr: fe80::cad6:5eff:fef8:6a22/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:384 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:297 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:119746 (119.7 KB)  TX bytes:37055 (37.0 KB)
          Interrupt:46 Base address:0x4000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:62 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:62 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4712 (4.7 KB)  TX bytes:4712 (4.7 KB)

mon.wlan0 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-26-5E-E8-4F-8E-30-30-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2514 (2.5 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:5e:e8:4f:8e  
          inet6 addr: fe80::226:5eff:fee8:4f8e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:187 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12139 (12.1 KB)  TX bytes:82155 (82.1 KB)
```

It had looked like a problem with iptables, but no.

Comment: Please add the output of `ip route`, `brctl show`, and `ifconfig` to your question. In particular I'm wondering about what interface your default route is trying to use. Can you ping 192.168.1.1?

Comment: @JohnSGruber Thanks for your kindly help, I have resolved this issue, before I setup bridge, I added NAT to iptables, maybe it caused this issue. After I reboot OS, this bridge works.

Comment: @JohnSGruber Excuse me, I encounter this issue again, the browser can not open web due to look up DNS failed. I append some info to my question.

Comment: Would you append the output of `ip route`? I'd like to see how 192.168.1.x and default are routed, including interfaces.